# how to add linked work item to each of the story in tfs

Tags: visual-studio-2010

in VS2010 tfs , I want to add 5 new linked tasks (documentation, unit test, UAT, etc) to each user story and they all have different Ids.I have currently have 50+ user stories,what's the best approach? 
Are there any queries/templates that i can write/use to do the job?
thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use Excel to edit/add multiple work items.

Look here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd286627.aspx